# Lightsaber claws in Expanded Universe?

Tags: star-wars, comics, lightsaber, star-wars-legends

This may be a bit of a weird question, but here goes; have any notable Sith or Jedi used 'lightsaber claws' in the expanded Star Wars universe?

The reason why I asked this is because I remember an interesting comic in which one of the canon Jedi (I don't recall who it was, possibly Obi-Wan), traveled to a temple to assassinate a Sith/Dark Jedi who wielded such a weapon, getting past his guards by mind-tricking them. Despite being very portly in build, the target managed to fight several bouts before ultimately falling, though not before seeing a vision of countless souls.

I know this was an official Star Wars comic due to reading it in an anthology, but all attempts to dig up its identity have proven fruitless (e.g. the only character I have found who used a similar variant is Kinsuj Inkstu, and he's an Exodus character!). Thus, I hope to find out who drew that comic and what characters featured in it with this question, as well as learn about a fascinating lightsaber variant.

EDIT: I think I've actually found the comic I was thinking of; its title is 'Survivors', and it was published in Star Wars Tales #13 (the fact that the Tales series are classified as 'infinities' explains why they don't show up even in Legends continuity). Mace Windu was the Jedi in that comic (shows just how badly I've remembered it, given how Windu's the polar opposite of Kenobi!), and the target was a Near-Human called Uda Khalid, some obscure dictator who only appeared in that one comic. The weapon he used wasn't a lightsaber but rather a 'fire knife', an energy-blade tool similar to a laser-knife that he weaponised by strapping two to his wrist.

Despite finding out the identity of that comic, my initial question still stands, so input is very welcome.

Comment: i want light saber claws, omg.

Comment: Concept art for Plo Koon has him using something like what you describe, although they ended up giving him a more "normal" lightsaber in the films.

Comment: Make that edit an answer.

Comment: I've just searched all 300(ish) star wars EU novels. No mention of "Lightsaber claws"

Comment: @Richard I would, though that comic was only a facet of my main question, which is about the presence of wrist-mounted/claw type lightsabers in the Star Wars universe in general. Thus, I haven't really answered my own question yet.

Comment: This smells a lot like a bad list question add it's so open ended (and therefore to broad).

Comment: what about [this guy](http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20090521184317/starwars/images/thumb/c/c8/Lord_Nyax.jpg/250px-Lord_Nyax.jpg)? [Irek Ismaren](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Irek_Ismaren) had  lightsaber blades implanted into his wrists, elbows, and knees.

Answer (score 7):

The closest would probably be the "lightsaber gauntlet," as shown in some *Revenge of the Sith* concept art and later featured on an action figure.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like a cross between a Jedi and Wolverine.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit of an odd match, but could you possibly be thinking about Joruus C'Boath from the cover picture of "Heir to the Empire"?

The light emanating from his fingers is supposed to be Force-lightning, but it could easily be mistaken for lightsaber claws.

[image]